# Chrome handler confirmation - get user's choice in JS?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How to get user's response in JS from [this window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK0wt.png)?

Comment: Copy that image in the question itself (inline image), instead as a link.

Comment: I need at least 10 points to make inline images

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default confirm box:

```js
if (confirm('Open Office ?')) {
    // Do something if user clicks Yes
} else {
    // Do nothing
}
```

Or using the **jQuery UI Dialog box**: **https://jqueryui.com/dialog/**